# Disable reverse path filtering from Linux kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Within a Linux kernel module, I need to disable rp_filter in some way.
This would typically be possible from user-space via a couple of simple sysctl calls :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.[ifname].rp_filter=0
```

How can I achieve the same result from kernel space? My first idea is that I probably need to write into the relative proc files. If so, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you change the implementation of `net/ipv4/devinet.c` ?

Comment: Nope. I believe there should be some API somewhere to do this without hacking.. 
Basically I'd just need to know where the rp_filter flag is intercepted within the kernel, and from there follow the calls path

Comment: I've checked. you can't access it directly, as it's defined static in the module. it's not exported. There are few exported functions, you can check if they allow access to that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the implementation of `sysctl` in the kernel, and I've found that doing a `sysctl` is just the same as writing a value to a file in the `/proc` filesystem.

In your case you just want to do the equivalent of:

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

Here is a rough code sample, based on what I see in the kernel code I am reading just now:

```
struct vfsmount *mnt;
struct file *file;
ssize_t result;
char *pathname = "sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter";
int flags = O_WRONLY;

mnt = task_active_pid_ns(current)->proc_mnt;
file = file_open_root(mnt->mnt_root, mnt, pathname, flags);
result = PTR_ERR(file);
if (IS_ERR(file)) {
  // oops, something bad happened
} else {
  char *buffer = "\0";
  result = kernel_write(file, buffer, 1, 0); // last 2 args are 'count' and 'pos'
  if (result < 0) {
    // oops, something else bad happened
  }
}
fput(file);
```

This is just a rough sample, so you will have to do your own research and testing to get it working. Good luck!

Comment: I'm just looking at the implementation for that `/proc` file, if you want to bypass the filesystem... it's in `net/ipv4/devinet.c`. I haven't figured out how to use it directly yet.

Comment: Hmm. As @stdcall said, none of the relevant functions are exported from `devinet.c`. It looks like accessing it through a VFS call to `procfs` is probably the most reliable way of doing things.

Comment: Basically,  You don't want to open a file in the kernel.  Make sure that the file system is mounted before your module tries to access the file

Comment: If I had a chance to avoid opening userspace file I would be glad to use any API that would prevent it.. In the end there must be something somewhere that reads the content of the rp_filter file and handles that.

Comment: As I said, the above rough code sample is based on the syscall handler for `sysctl`. So if this is poor style, then that existing kernel code is written poorly.