# How to receive a UDP broadcast sent to 255.255.255.255 using boost asio?

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I have written a device discovery program that can run in client or server mode.  In client mode it sends a UDP broadcast packet to 255.255.255.255 on port 30000 and then listens for responses on port 30001.  In server mode it listens for a UDP broadcast on port 30000 and sends a UDP broadcast packet to 255.255.255.255 on port 30001 in response.

When I run this program on 2 devices with IP addresses 192.168.10.61 and 192.168.10.62 it all works perfectly.  The whole point of this program is to allow devices with unknown IP addresses to discover one another so  long as they are connected to the same physical network.  So to test that, I changed the IP address of the first device to something random like 12.34.56.42/255.255.240.  And now it stops working.

Using tcpdump on the 192.168.10.62 machine I can see that the UDP packet from the 12.134.56.42 machine was received:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 port 30000 -c 1 -v
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:38:02.552427 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18835, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 49)
12.34.56.42.56815 > 255.255.255.255.30000: UDP, length 21
1 packet captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

but my discovery program no longer receives it.  This is the code I am using to receive the UDP broadcast packets:

```
int WaitForPacket(uint16_t portNum, vector<char>& udpBuf, udp::endpoint& remoteEndpoint, const chrono::milliseconds timeout)
{
    io_service ioService;

    udp::socket socket(ioService, udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), portNum));
    socket.set_option(socket_base::broadcast(true));

    boost::system::error_code error;
    int numBytes = receive_from(socket, buffer(udpBuf), remoteEndpoint, error, timeout);

    if (error && error != error::message_size && error != error::timed_out)
    {
        printf("Got error: %s\n", error.message().c_str());
        return -1;
    }

    return numBytes;
}

/*
 * The boost asio library does not provide a blocking read with timeout function so we have to roll our own.
 */
int receive_from(
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket&         socket,
    const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1& buf,
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint&       remoteEndpoint,
    boost::system::error_code&            error,
    chrono::milliseconds                  timeout)
{
    volatile bool ioDone = false;
    int numBytesReceived = 0;
    boost::asio::io_service& ioService = socket.get_io_service();    

    socket.async_receive_from(buf, remoteEndpoint,
                              [&error, &ioDone, &numBytesReceived](const boost::system::error_code& errorAsync, size_t bytesReceived)
                              {
                                  ioDone = true;
                                  error = errorAsync;
                                  numBytesReceived = bytesReceived;
                              });

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
    ioService.reset();
    ioService.poll_one();

    auto endTime = chrono::system_clock::now() + timeout;

    while (!ioDone)
    {
        ioService.reset();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
        if (now > endTime)
        {
            socket.cancel();
            error = error::timed_out;
            return 0;
        }
        ioService.poll_one();
    }
    ioService.reset();

    return numBytesReceived;
}
```

I checked similar questions on Stack Overflow and found some that said the receiving socket has to be bound to INADDR_ANY in order to receive broadcast packets.  I was originally creating the socket like this `udp::socket socket(ioService, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), portNum));` but  have now changed it to use `ip::address_v4::any()` instead.  That didn't make any difference.

Can anybody tell me what I need to change in order to receive the UDP broadcast packet as expected ?

I am running this on iMX6 devices running Linux and am compiling using boost 1.58.

Comment: You are not receiving datagrams because by changing the first address to 12.34.56.42/255.255.240 you automatically excluded the computer from the local network address wise. And since broadcasting only works in LAN environments this is why you are not fully getting the message. Your computer might be connected to the same network with spoof IP and that spoof IP is the reason it doesn't fully receive the broadcast message.

Comment: You might need to set up a private network for the discoverable devices that they would all be connected to prior discovery, but that isn't really discovery. What you could do though is leave your WLAN open and apply this to visitors that connect to your router.

Comment: One way to deal with arbitrary addresses would be to manually set the sender's IP address in the broadcast packets to 0.0.0.0 (this is basically how DHCP is working, too). Don't ask me how to achieve this with boost. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196466/in-boost-asio-how-can-i-set-the-source-ip-address-to-impersonate-another-server is helpful as far as I can see.

Comment: @Ivan86 I thought the distinction between the network broadcast address (192.168.10.255) and the UDP broadcast address (255.255.255.255) existed for exactly this purpose.  If you can only send packets to addresses on the same IP network as yourself then the 255.255.255.255 address is unnecessary.  As the tcpdump command shows, the packet has been received but something in the network stack discarded it.  Packets like this are used in ARP and DHCP so it is definitely possible, just maybe not at the boost asio UDP layer.

Comment: @Christop Freundl, thanks for the advice.  I will experiment with setting the sender IP to 0.0.0.0 and see if that makes any difference on the receiving side.

Comment: Check to see if `Block LAN to WAN Multicast and Broadcast data` is set in the wireless settings or your router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally discovered why my code was never seeing the broadcast packets even though tcpdump proved that they were being received.  After finding this StackOverflow question:

[Disable reverse path filtering from Linux kernel space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000939/disable-reverse-path-filtering-from-linux-kernel-space)

it seems that I just needed to disable Reverse Path Filtering on both hosts like this:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
```

and then my code worked perfectly with no modifications.  Hopefully this will help other people wondering why they can't get UDP broadcasts to the network broadcast address (255.255.255.255) to work.

Comment: You are a life-saver! Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add that  I eventually switched to using IPv6 instead of IPv4 due to issues on Windows 7 where I couldn't find a way to add a link local IPv4 address to an interface that was configured using DHCP.  IPv6 works much better for device discovery as you automatically get a link local address configured so you can just send a UDP broadcast to FF02::1.  No need to hassle with disabling Reverse Path Filtering and no problems setting up a link local address on Windows 7.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the info.