# Why can tcpdump receive UDP broadcasts that netcat or socat can't?

Tags: linux, udp, tcpdump, netcat

I have a separate modem and router, configured with the modem as a bridge.  The modem hosts a LAN where it has IP address of 192.186.2.1.  In order to be able to [access the modem's web UI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/access.modem.through.nat), the router has an extra interface on the WAN port with a fixed IP address (192.168.2.10) in the modem's LAN.

The modem broadcasts VDSL status data via UDP.  I would like to listen to these packets on my router but I can't capture them using `netcat` or `socat`.  They are definitely there, though, because they show up in TCP dump.

```bash
# tcpdump -i wan broadcast -v
tcpdump: listening on wan, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:19:25.579815 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 54981, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    0.0.0.0.13253 > 255.255.255.255.4944: UDP, length 116
14:19:35.580363 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 54982, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    0.0.0.0.13306 > 255.255.255.255.4944: UDP, length 116
14:19:45.580894 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 54983, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    0.0.0.0.13368 > 255.255.255.255.4944: UDP, length 116
```

but `socat` (using so-bindtodevice described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663180) doesn't see anything...

```bash
# socat -v udp-recv:4944,so-bindtodevice=wan -

<nothing happens>
```

...and neither does `netcat` (specifying the interface as here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368690).

```bash
# netcat -v -ul 4944 -s 192.168.2.10

<nothing happens>
```

Why doesn't `socat` receive the broadcast packets?  How can I configure things so that it does?

##### Background info

- Modem: Draytek Vigor 130 (3.8.5_BT)
- Router: Linksys WRT1900ACS (OpenWrt 22.03.2)

WAN and bridge interfaces on the router, WAN port is connected to modem:

```bash
# ip a
...
7: wan@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 5a:ef:68:b7:05:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global wan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 79.71.35.166/19 brd 79.71.63.255 scope global wan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::58ef:68ff:feb7:5bc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 58:ef:68:b7:05:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br-lan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fde7:9501:870b::1/60 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5aef:68ff:feb7:5bc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Routing table shows 192.168.2.0 uses WAN interface.

```bash
# ip route
default via 79.71.32.1 dev wan  src 79.71.35.166 
79.71.32.0/19 dev wan scope link  src 79.71.35.166 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br-lan scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wan scope link  src 192.168.2.10
```

Software versions.

```bash
# tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.9.3
libpcap version 1.10.1 (with TPACKET_V3)


# netcat --version
netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1
Copyright (C) 2002 - 2003  Giovanni Giacobbi

This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

Original idea and design by Avian Research <hobbit@avian.org>,
Written by Giovanni Giacobbi <giovanni@giacobbi.net>.


# socat -V
socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
socat version 1.7.4.1 on 1672494323
   running on Linux version #0 SMP Fri Oct 14 22:44:41 2022, release 5.10.146, machine armv7l
features:
  #define WITH_STDIO 1
  #define WITH_FDNUM 1
  #define WITH_FILE 1
  #define WITH_CREAT 1
  #define WITH_GOPEN 1
  #define WITH_TERMIOS 1
  #define WITH_PIPE 1
  #define WITH_UNIX 1
  #define WITH_ABSTRACT_UNIXSOCKET 1
  #define WITH_IP4 1
  #define WITH_IP6 1
  #define WITH_RAWIP 1
  #define WITH_GENERICSOCKET 1
  #define WITH_INTERFACE 1
  #define WITH_TCP 1
  #define WITH_UDP 1
  #define WITH_SCTP 1
  #define WITH_LISTEN 1
  #define WITH_SOCKS4 1
  #define WITH_SOCKS4A 1
  #define WITH_VSOCK 1
  #define WITH_PROXY 1
  #define WITH_SYSTEM 1
  #define WITH_EXEC 1
  #undef WITH_READLINE
  #define WITH_TUN 1
  #define WITH_PTY 1
  #undef WITH_OPENSSL
  #undef WITH_FIPS
  #undef WITH_LIBWRAP
  #define WITH_SYCLS 1
  #define WITH_FILAN 1
  #define WITH_RETRY 1
  #define WITH_MSGLEVEL 0 /*debug*/
```

Reverse path filtering is disabled (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256271/3508733)

```bash
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter 
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wan/rp_filter 
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
0
```

Adding broadcast options to `netcat` and `socat` didn't help:

```bash
# netcat -v -ul 4944 -s 192.168.2.10 -b
netcat: unrecognized option: b
Try `netcat --help' for more information.
```

```bash
# socat -v -d -d udp4-recv:4944,so-bindtodevice=wan,so-broadcast -
2023/01/03 16:42:17 socat[10747] N reading from and writing to stdio
2023/01/03 16:42:17 socat[10747] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]

<nothing happens>
```

Comment: `255.255.255.255` is a broadcast address, not UDP unicast. Maybe setting the `broadcast` socket option for `socat` (or adding `-b` for `netcat`)  will help.

Comment: It didn't seem to help `socat` and my `netcat` version doesn't support `-b`. I've updated the question.  Thanks anyway for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

### It works with *socat* and *netcat*

What seems to be wrong with your example, you put your source address,
but you didnt put destnation address, and you want to sent packets.
Instead you configured *netcat* for listening.

I used your *socat* with my specific setting broadcast UDP packet:

```
^Cdrazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~$ socat -v udp-recv:4944,so-bindtodevice=wlo1 -
> 2023/12/01 13:42:43.921297  length=12 from=5 to=16
testing1
testing1
> 2023/12/01 13:43:08.252901  length=15 from=17 to=31
testing2......
testing2......
> 2023/12/01 13:43:23.456512  length=15 from=32 to=46
testing3------
testing3------
> 2023/12/01 13:51:19.697565  length=8 from=47 to=54
TEST OK
TEST OK
```

It will work without `so-bindtodevice` if you have only one network interface,as *socat* will listen on it.

I rewrited your *netcat* command for sending broadcast packets:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~$ netcat -v -ub 255.255.255.255 4944 -s 192.168.0.17
Connection to 255.255.255.255 4944 port [udp/*] succeeded!
testing1
testing2......                                       
testing3------
TEST OK
```

What your command did wrong it used listening flag `-l` instead of broadcast flag `-b`, and it lacked destination address `255.255.255.255`

Again, it will work without specifying your source address `-s` as UDP packet already have that information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite understand.  Why do `socat` and `netcat` need to broadcast the packets? I am trying to _capture_ packets sent by the modem.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didnt understand your configuration the best. I thought you were playing with sending packets from socat to netcat. Now As I understand you try to capture broadcast packets comming from DSL modem on an `wan` interface with socat or netcat command? Where you execute commands from? Router on PC  on 12.168.1.x LAN?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'm trying to execute the commands on the router.  Ideally, I'd forward the packets onto some other machine on 127.168.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with the exact setup you have described.

The following worked for me to be able to capture the packets.

```
[admin@pf:/root]: nc -ul 4944 -v 
Connection from 0.0.0.0 33232 received!
 R ��.
�����`��TjH�`w�]0�����s%ݘ��y`^N�������H��rv
                                ��:���9r�w���5A�%�
```

So far I have been unsuccessful in decoding the protocol myself and it appears a previous request for information from Draytek in July 2023 was also [unsuccessful](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/34k6kqzk)